# How to make a zero matrix with one row

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix in Matlab with one row, how can I do it?

I know this:

```
y=zeros(5)
```

but Unfortunately it gives a squired matrix

Comment: `zeros(1,5)`. The first index represents the # of rows and, guess what, the 2nd represents the # of columns!. Have you looked at the docs? I highly recommend you do that if you plan to use Matlab in a near future; that's really the basics. Have fun!

Comment: The documentation on `zeros` is [very clear](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html?refresh=true) on its usage. Consider doing a quick google search for the function of interest (or just type `help function_name` in MATLAB) before asking stack overflow.

Comment: Consult the duplicate.  Replace 90 with 5.

Answer (score 3):

You should use instead `y=zeros(1,5)`